# How to Install .iPA File Install By Using iTunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I am trying to generate `.iPA` file by using `non paided apple id` within real device connected `Xcode`.

In the past `iTunes versions` we can install `.iPA` file via drag and drop on my apps place.

Now I am not getting that same view. Please find below `images`. I am using `iOS 9.1 with iTunes 12.3.1.23`

[image]